# Отдельные файлы для IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Всем привет, как вы считаете стоит ли для каждой версии браузера ie делать отдельный файл css? или достаточно выделить какую-та определённую версию ie?
И ещё как быть с 10 версией ie которая не реагирует на комментарий <!--[if IE 10]> <![endif]-->

Comment: вы используете какой нибудь готовый framework?

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет, имхо, не стоит. Все-таки не настолько много вещей, которые IE (начиная с, наверное, 9, про 8 не помню) не поддурживает.
2. Воспользуйтесь css-хаком:

   [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) screen and (min-width:0\0) 
   { 
       /*ваш css*/
   }

Comment: *Оффтоп*. Блин, ну когда же уже для осла не нужно будет никаких хаков?! Уже про девятую версию начинаем забывать, а это "чудо" до сих пор кривое. @Макс Жуков, это я не в ваш огород камень ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/iZ7fP9z.gif

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя modernizr использовать для тех стилей, которые ie (и др. браузеры) не поддерживает?

Answer (score 0):

для 10 и 11 версии подключается так

<![if IE]>Вы используйете IE<![endif]>

Comment: Как и для все остальных браузеров.

Answer (score 0):

Поддержка условных комментариев в стандартном режиме и режиме совместимости Internet Explorer 10 была удалена для улучшения взаимодействия и совместимости с HTML5. Это означает, что условные комментарии теперь обрабатываются как обычные комментарии, так же как в других браузерах.

Страница, использующая условные комментарии, работает нормально в Windows **Internet Explorer 9**, но не работает в **Internet Explorer 10**.

Если эта страница нормально работает в других браузерах, попробуйте использовать обнаружение возможностей, чтобы взаимодействовать с **Internet Explorer 10**, так же как с другими браузерами. Либо добавьте в начало страницы следующий тег **meta**, задающий выбор поведения **Internet Explorer 9**:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

Примерно так:

<html>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
      <!--[if IE]>
        This content is ignored in Internet Explorer 10 and other browsers.
        In older versions of Internet Explorer, it renders as part of the page.
      <![endif]-->
    </html>
```

Теперь на счет хаков:

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
        /* стили только для IE9 - IE10 */ 
    }

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* стили только для IE10 */
}
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

не очень хороший совет.

Comment: это как вариант - но это не есть правило. Мое мнение вообще как можно меньше использовать хаков или к этому стремиться

Answer (score 0):

Отличная статья на данную тему:
https://www.kobzarev.com/makeup/ie10-css-hacks/

Мой любимый хак:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* стили только для IE10 и 11 */ 
}
```